# How to get watchdog_timer package

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, teleoperation, download

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using ROS Fuerte and am trying to find a ROS watchdog service to use in a teleoperation program.  I found the package watchdog timer on the ROS Wiki, but it does not show up in my current stacks.  I would like to download it, but can not locate it or a stack which contains it in apt-get, etc.  I would appreciate it if someone could let me know if watchdog_timer is available to download for Fuerte and how to get it or if there is another way to implement a watchdog.  Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/79806/how-to-get-watchdog_timer-package/) by [HITE](https://answers.ros.org/users/2521/hite/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2013-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved.  Documentation at http://ftp.isr.ist.utl.pt/pub/roswiki/watchdog_timer.html.

---

Originally posted by [HITE](https://answers.ros.org/users/2521/hite/) with karma: 92 on 2013-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0